# NSCollectionView memory problems

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My environment is Yosemite 10.10.5 with Xcode 7.2 using ARC.

I have an application that uses a `NSCollectionView` and experiences continuous memory growth.  I've been able to create a tiny example that shows the same type of behaviour.

I start with a view controller that has a collection view property.

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSCollectionView *collectionView;
```

The view controller sets the prototype cell for that view.  The .xib for the prototype contains a top-level view, and an image button as its only subview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.collectionView setItemPrototype:[[CollectionViewItem alloc] initWithNibName:@"CollectionViewItem"
                                                                               bundle:nil]];
}
```

I simulate data refreshes by creating a timer when the view appears and running it every two seconds.  When the timer fires, it executes a target method.

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    NSMutableArray *dataItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        CollectionDataItem *item = [[CollectionDataItem alloc] init];
        [dataItems addObject:item];
    }
    [self.collectionView setContent:dataItems];
}
```

The code for the `CollectionViewItem` simply sets a button image.  (I'm doing that because, in the original app, a lot of the excess memory was connected to image creation.)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    [super viewWillAppear];
    [self.theButton setImage:[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/pmills/Desktop/d20c9f20a50352593498c0e7633e3ae7.jpg"]];
}
```

When I profile the app with Instruments, I see that the top-level objects (`NSView`) loaded from the .xib file increase in number even though the `CollectionViewItem` count stays at five.  Drilling down shows me that each of the excess views has a retain count of two.  (With 72 retain/release/autorelease events for each view, I haven't figured out which retains are a problem...I'm working on it.)

Putting my `timerFired:` code in an autorelease section didn't help.  Specifically nil-ing the button's image and the button itself when the `CollectionViewItem` disappears didn't help, likewise nothing changed by trying to replace its loaded view with an empty one.

What am I missing?

-- UPDATE --

After much experimenting, I realized that this doesn't always happen.  It seems related to whether the application is processing (mouse?) events.  That is, if I sit and watch Instruments while the app is running, memory increases as described here.  If I bring the app to the foreground (or move a mouse around while it's in the foreground), the backlog of objects is cleared.

This isn't a solution but maybe it will inspire one.  :)

Comment: You're allocating an image and setting it as the button's image every time in viewWillAppear. Shouldn't that be in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I'll try your suggestion.  I don't think it will make a difference because the main problem is with the button's superview hanging around after the `CollectionViewItem` is deallocated.  But, at this point, it's worth trying.

Comment: @rocky As I suspected, there's no difference in behaviour.  (I think I put it into `viewWillAppear` so that I could try to influence its removal in `viewDidDisappear`...which didn't help either.)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing same problem. Memory footprint of application kept increasing. After debugging I found that even `deinit` of `NSCollectionView` and `NSViewController` is being called however `NSCollectionItem` cells are stranded in memory and not being deallocated. Continuous increase of `NSCollectionItem` cells in memory increased memory footprint of application tremendously.

[image]

> **Solution:** When `NSCollectionItem` is created with custom class, FileOwner is set to CustomClassName by default, clearing this solved
>   the proved and deallocated `NSCollectionItem` cells from memory.

[image]